# How to build executable js file by webpack in nextjs?

Tags: javascript, webpack, next.js, build, config

I am struggling with webpack and want some help.
I wanted to build specific file called DOMEvaluator.ts to js file which is executable.
However, when I build it by webpack, it is returned as below.

DOMEvaluator.ts (BEFORE BUILT)

```js
import { DOMMessage, DOMMessageResponse } from '../types';
console.log('contentjs');

const messagesFromReactAppListener = (
  msg: DOMMessage,
  sender: chrome.runtime.MessageSender,
  sendResponse: (response: DOMMessageResponse) => void,
) => {
  console.log('[content.js]. Message received', msg);

  const response: DOMMessageResponse = {
    title: document.title,
    headlines: Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName<'h1'>('h1')).map(
      h1 => h1.innerText,
    ),
  };

  console.log('[content.js]. Message response', response);

  sendResponse(response);

  return undefined;
};

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(messagesFromReactAppListener);
```

```
// runtime can't be in strict mode because a global variable is assign and maybe created.
(self["webpackChunk_N_E"] = self["webpackChunk_N_E"] || []).push([[998],{

/***/ 8511:
/***/ (function(__unused_webpack_module, __webpack_exports__, __webpack_require__) {

"use strict";
__webpack_require__.r(__webpack_exports__);
console.log("contentjs");
const messagesFromReactAppListener = (msg, sender, sendResponse)=>{
    console.log("[content.js]. Message received", msg);
    const response = {
        title: document.title,
        headlines: Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName("h1")).map((h1)=>h1.innerText)
    };
    console.log("[content.js]. Message response", response);
    sendResponse(response);
    return undefined;
};
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(messagesFromReactAppListener);



/***/ })

},
/******/ function(__webpack_require__) { // webpackRuntimeModules
/******/ var __webpack_exec__ = function(moduleId) { return __webpack_require__(__webpack_require__.s = moduleId); }
/******/ var __webpack_exports__ = (__webpack_exec__(8511));
/******/ _N_E = __webpack_exports__;
/******/ }
]);
```

I wanted to make my built-js code start like,
`!function(){var t=...`

how can I get rid of webpack codes only on this DOMEvaluator file?
My next.config.js looks like below.

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const path = require('path');
const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  webpack: (config, { webpack, ...options }) => {
    if (!options.dev) {
      config.optimization.runtimeChunk = false;
      config.optimization.splitChunks = {
        cacheGroups: {
          default: false,
          vendors: false,
        },
      };

      config.optimization.minimize = false;
      const originalEntry = config.entry;
      config.entry = async () => {
        const entries = await originalEntry();
        entries['content'] = path.join(
          __dirname,
          'src',
          'chromeServices',
          'DOMEvaluator.ts',
        );
        return entries;
      };
    }

    return config;
  },
};

module.exports = nextConfig;
```

I've tried to install various plugins and change the setting of webpack.